# Sampling data from two collections with multiple array matching MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find all unread messages, by chat ID, and user ID. Unread message is if `chats_users.max_read_date` is less than `message.create_date` and `message.from_id` is not equal to user.

How it works now. I have an array of chat IDs, and I search all chats_users documents by `chat_id` and `user_id` and then just loop search for messages.

I'd like to rewrite it all into one query, but I'm running into a few problems. What is my problem, how do I find all `chats_users` by chat ID and user ID to then find all messages that are written by a non-user, and the creation date `message.create_date` is greater than `chats_users.max_read_date`

How to make a condition so that for each chat, find its chats_users and then select only those messages which are written not by the user who makes the request and all other chatters, and the creation date of the message `message.create_date` is greater than `chats_users.max_read_date`

Message collection

```golang
type ChatsUsers struct {
    ID     string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    ChatID string `json:"chat_id" bson:"chat_id"`
    // user ID, which corresponds to the user ID in the system.
    UserID string `json:"user_id" bson:"user_id"`
    // MaxReadDate time of the last message read
    MaxReadDate int64 `json:"max_read_date" bson:"max_read_date"`
}
```

ChatsUsers collection

```golang
type Message struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    ChatID     string `json:"chat_id" bson:"chat_id"`
    FromID     string `json:"from_id" bson:"from_id"`
    CreateDate int64  `json:"create_date" bson:"create_date"`
    Body     string `json:"body" bson:"body"`
}
```

```golang
Rewrite the query to get a single aggregation, the purpose of the query is to find all messages, by all chats that are unread and unscripted by a non-user, the uid variable is the user looking for such messages

fun (r *Mongo) UnreadMessageCount(ctx context.Context, chats []*Chat, uid string) (map[string]int64, error) {

    match := bson.A{}
    for _, chat := range chats {
        match = append(match, chat.ID)
    }

    chatsUsersList := make([]*domain.ChatsUsers, 0)
    for _, ch := range chats {
        chu, err := r.FindChatUser(ctx, ch.ID, uid)
        if err != nil {
            l.Error().Err(err).Msg("failed to find chat user")
            return nil, err
        }
        chatsUsersList = append(chatsUsersList, chu)
    }

    list := make([]*domain.Message, 0)

    for _, ch := range chats {
        for _, chu := range chatsUsersList {
            if chu.ChatID == ch.ID {
                filter := bson.D{
                    // search for messages by active chat IDs
                    { Key: "chat_id", Value: ch.ID},
                    // add filtering: that the message has not yet been read,
                    // and that the messages we select are not written by the current user.
                    {Key: "$and",
                        Value: bson.A{
                            bson.D{
                                {
                                    Key: "create_date", Value: bson.D{ bson.D{
                                    // $gt Matches values that are greater than the specified value.
                                    { Key: "$gt", Value: chu.MaxReadDate}}
                                },
                                // $ne Matches all values that are not equal to the specified value.
                                // https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/
                                {Key: "from_id", Value: bson.M{"$ne": uid}}
                            },
                        },
                    },
                }

                cursor, err := r.colMessage.Find(ctx, filter)
                ....

                var res []*domain.Message
                ....
            }
        }
    }

    // it doesn't make sense to use an array of messages, we need to create a map,
    // which will have the chat ID and the number of unread messages in it.
    messages := make(map[string]int64)
    for _, msg := range list {
        messages[msg.ChatID]++
    }

    return messages, nil
}
```

My try (sorry, but this is a very crooked query, but I'm still trying to write the right query)

```js
db.message.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        chat_id: {
                            $in: ["ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        from_id: {
                            $ne: "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1d"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $gt: ["$create_date", { $max: "$chats_users.max_read_date" }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "chatsusers",
            localField: "chat_id",
            foreignField: "chat_id",
            as: "chats_users"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$chats_users"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$chat_id",
            messages: {
                $push: {
                    id: "$id",
                    chat_id: "$chat_id",
                    from_id: "$from_id",
                    create_date: "$create_date",
                    type: "$type",
                    media: "$media",
                    body: "$body",
                    update_at: "$update_at",
                    modifications: "$modifications",
                    viewed: "$viewed"
                }
            },
            max_read_date: { $max: "$chats_users.max_read_date" }
        }
    }
]);
```

In the response I expect to get only four objects from the test data

```js
{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63f502d3c1be2b78aaa6152e"
      },
      "body": "полковник конь тобі копитом в грудь! 3",
      "chat_id": "ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2",
      "create_date": 1677001427977,
      "from_id": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1d5g",
      "id": "G30uZ1HvlYQCZVwRRTBi",
      "media": "",
      "modifications": null,
      "type": "text",
      "update_at": 0,
      "viewed": false
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63f502d2c1be2b78aaa6152d"
      },
      "body": "полковник конь тобі копитом в грудь! 2",
      "chat_id": "ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2",
      "create_date": 1677001428101,
      "from_id": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1d5g",
      "id": "RzrfvZuLWyhrKOHEx5gK",
      "media": "",
      "modifications": null,
      "type": "text",
      "update_at": 0,
      "viewed": false
    },

    {
      "_id": {"$oid": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2bb2"},
      "body": "after you",
      "chat_id": "ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2-y7y3r2",
      "create_date": 1677001427398,
      "from_id": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b23",
      "id": "e5189d64-0c43-41dd-befa-f554d09475cf",
      "media": "",
      "modifications": null,
      "type": "text",
      "update_at": 0,
      "viewed": true
    },
    {
      "_id": {"$oid": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2bb1"},
      "body": "I'm not religious",
      "chat_id": "ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2-y7y3r2",
      "create_date": 1677001427327,
      "from_id": "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b23",
      "id": "a1fbc6b0-5f8d-4fa2-aef7-807314dfba0d",
      "media": "",
      "modifications": null,
      "type": "text",
      "update_at": 0,
      "viewed": true
    }
```

[Test data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JWUtFcLBKS2)

And my second try

```js
db.chats_users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            user_id: "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1d",
            chat_id: { $in: ["ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2"] },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "message",
            let: { chat_id: "$chat_id", max_read_date: "$max_read_date" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ["$chat_id", "$$chat_id"] },
                                { $ne: ["$from_id", "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1d"] },
                                { $gt: ["$create_date", "$$max_read_date"] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "messages"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            chat_id: 1,
            message_count: { $size: "$messages" }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be simpler, I made a query using the `chatsusers` collection - which simplified the query.

```js
db.chatsusers.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            chat_id: {
                $in: ["ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2", "22e1e6f1-459a-4ed1-bc8f-c9947492972d"],
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "message",
            localField: "chat_id",
            foreignField: "chat_id",
            let: { chat_id: "$chat_id", max_read_date: "$max_read_date" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ["$chat_id", "$$chat_id"] },
                                { $ne: ["$from_id", "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1e"] },
                                { $gt: ["$create_date", "$$max_read_date"] },
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                }
            ],
            as: "messages"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            chat_id: 1,
            message_count: { $size: "$messages" },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$chat_id",
            message_count: { $sum: "$message_count" },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { "message_count": -1 },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            chat_id: "$_id",
            message_count: 1,
        },
    },
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dufPDpjImSD)